# how do i fill this hole while maintainingg the curvature of the whole model

Tags: modeling

[image]

What would be the easiest way to fill this hole, while still maintaining the curvature of the rest of the model? ive tried extruding the edge that goes down the middle and then filling the two holes,  however the new edges do not follow the form. the only solution that i can think of with my limited knowledge is to extrude the selected faces and then merge the vertices to create a smooth finish.

Comment: And a Sphere and use Shrinkwrap modifier for this Vertex Group? ...

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE! Can you share the blend file? https://blend-exchange.com